# Regex with qoutemark mode

Tags: regex, expression

I need to get all variables inside expression. I.e. we have an expression:

```
1+x1-func(x2, 12*x3, 'string')/(x1-5)
```

so, variables are: x1, x2, x3

I have the following regex:

```
\b((?>[_A-Za-z]\w+)|[A-Za-z]\b)(?!\()(?!\')
```

it works for expression like above. But in case with quotemarks it does not:

12+x1+455+'ggg+4+rrr+tt'+3

It found x1, ggg, rrr.

https://www.regex101.com/r/H8hlOr/1

but 'ggg+4+rrr+tt' is a constant. Should be found only x1 in this case. Need to have 'quote mode', ignore all matches while quote is not closed. How to modify my expression to do it?

Comment: See [this regex variation](https://www.regex101.com/r/H8hlOr/3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current expression can be reduced to `\b[_A-Za-z]\w*\b(?![('])`.

- `(?>[_A-Za-z]\w+)` contains a redundant atomic group
- `\b([_A-Za-z]\w+|[A-Za-z]\b)` is matching 1 letter whole word or a whole word starting with a letter and then having 1+ word chars -> it can be reduced to `\b[_A-Za-z]\w*\b`
- `(?!\()(?!\')` are two consecutive lookaheads executed at the same location, they may be turned into  1 lookahead with alternation: `(?![('])`.

## PCRE

To skip all matches inside quotes, you may use SKIP-FAIL verbs: [`'[^']*'(*SKIP)(*F)|\b[_A-Za-z]\w*\b(?![('])`](https://www.regex101.com/r/FtwAkx/1).

Here, `'[^']*'` matches a single quoted substring and `(*SKIP)(*F)` force the regex engine to discard the match and start looking for the next match from the end of that match.

## .NET

In .NET and most other flavors, match *and capture* what you need and only match what you do not need:

```
'[^']*'|\b([_A-Za-z]\w*)\b(?![('])
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%27%5b%5e%27%5d*%27%7c%5cb%28%5b_A-Za-z%5d%5cw*%29%5cb%28%3f!%5b%28%27%5d%29&i=12%2bx1%2b455%2b%27ggg%2b4%2brrr%2btt%27%2b3).

Comment: Thank you, but does not work in .NET, Regex class :(

Comment: You did not mention the regex flavor and posted a PCRE regex fiddle. In .NET, capture what you need and only match what you do not need: [`'[^']*'|\b([_A-Za-z]\w*)\b(?![('])`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%27%5b%5e%27%5d*%27%7c%5cb%28%5b_A-Za-z%5d%5cw*%29%5cb%28%3f!%5b%28%27%5d%29&i=12%2bx1%2b455%2b%27ggg%2b4%2brrr%2btt%27%2b3).

Comment: It finds it - so what? Just ignore it. That is the point of *capturing*. You put those matches into Group 1 that you need.